# How can I get last modified timestamp in Lua

Tags: file, lua, timestamp, file-handling, last-modified

I am trying to work on Lua file handling. I am able to open (read), write and close the file via:

```lua
local session_debug = io.open("/root/session_debug.txt", "a")
session_debug:write("Some text\n")
session_debug:close()
```

How can I find the timestamp of when the file was last modified?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no built-in function in standard Lua that does this. One way to get it without third-party libraries is to take use of `io.popen`.

For example, on Linux, you could use [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat):

```
local f = io.popen("stat -c %Y testfile")
local last_modified = f:read()
```

Now `last_modified` is the timestamp of the last modified time of `testfile`. On my system,

```
print(os.date("%c", last_modified))
```

Outputs `Sat Mar 22 08:36:50 2014`.

Comment: In *BSD, including Mac OS X, it's `stat -f %m`.

Comment: If you want the date as a string, use `stat -c %y` in POSIX.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `stat` on windows?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind using a library, [`LuaFileSystem`](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html) allows you to get the modified timestamp as follows:

```
local t = lfs.attributes(path, 'modification')
```

A more elaborate example with error handling (will print the name and date of modification of the first argument passed to the script):

```
local lfs = require('lfs')
local time, err = lfs.attributes(arg[1], 'modification')
if err then
    print(err)
else
    print(arg[1], os.date("%c", time))
end
```