# Get file creation time with lua

Tags: file, time, lua

How do I get the time that a file was created?

What I have found:
The lfs library for Lua contains a method to get file attributes. However, the only ones that seem to get close to answering my question are those:

- access - time of last access
- modification - time of last data modification
- change - time of last file status change

None of them, by their descriptions, check for the creation time specifically.
I've been googling for a while and can't find the answer.

EDIT: I'm on a windows system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows command-line provides the argument `/T:C` to show the file creation date/time when used in context of `dir` command.

So, you can use the `io.popen` function as follows:

```
local sOut = io.popen( "dir /T:C *files*", "r" )
local sData = sOut:read "*a"
-- process sData as string to filter content as your needs
```

Comment: I never even thought I could do it like that.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Unix, you can't. There are three members related to time in [`struct stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/stat.h.html):

- `st_atime`   Time of last access.
- `st_mtime`   Time of last data modification.
- `st_ctime`   Time of last status change.

Some people misunderstood `st_ctime` for file creation time, but that's not true. File creation time is not preserved in Unix-style system.

The closest is *last status change* time, which you could get with [`lfs` library](https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html#reference), or, read [How can I get last modified timestamp in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33296834/1009479) for a solution without third-part libraries.

Comment: I forgot to mention it earlier, but I'm on a windows system.

Answer (score 0):

As somebody told before there is no create date attribute for file in Linux.

Use `stat` utility in Linux. It works for modern file systems.
To get last modified timestamp use

```bash
stat -c %Y [path_to_file]
```

So, you may use Lua's `io.popen` to execute and capture output

```lua
handle = io.popen("stat -c %Y /.dockerenv")
result = handle:read("*n")
handle:close()
```

Here is the reference - [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html)