# Is there any way to access local date/time in Lua without using the OS library?

Tags: date, time, lua

I'm a novice programmer, so apologies in advance if I use imprecise terminology.

I'm currently working with the Binding of Isaac: Afterbirth+ Lua modding API, which [according to the developer of Atom-boilua](https://atom.io/packages/atom-boilua) uses Lua 5.3 . I want to read the user's local date and time, but unfortunately the API prevents use of the OS (and I/O) libraries, for security reasons. That means that os.date() is unavailable, and the API itself doesn't have any built-in functions to read the date and time on the local machine.

So since the API doesn't have any way of doing this, I was wondering if there might be a way of doing it with Lua alone, without using os.date().

Things the API supports:

- Reading/Writing to a single text file
- Support for lua files other than main.lua which can be accessed using require()
- [JSON4Lua](https://github.com/craigmj/json4lua)

Things the API does not support (as far as I know):

- Complex libraries, ie with files distributed throughout folders. You can include folders with the mod files, but I don't think the API lets you access them properly. (It's very possible that I'm wrong about this and just haven't figured it out yet.)
- Installing libraries period - you can pretty much only ship mods with whatever files can go in the same directory as the main mod file.

Is there any way of accessing date/time within these restrictions, or am I just out of luck?

Comment: Can you create a text file, then read the created or last updated time? Is the 'os' module available at all?

Comment: No, as far as I'm aware the os module is completely disabled. 

There's an outside chance I can access the time the file was last modified, though. That might be worth something. Can I do that without the os and i/o libraries?

Comment: Actually, [it seems this isn't possible without I/O or external libraries.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296834/how-can-i-get-last-modified-timestamp-in-lua) So it looks like I'm just out of luck here, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you make a web service call though?

Comment: No, it seems networking is impossible without the user enabling the "--luadebug" launch option, which defeats the purpose because that would enable the os library anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way with Lua alone, without the os library, to get the current data/time. The os library is THE interface between the Lua runtime and the underlying OS.