# Lua Get File Last Modification Time

Tags: lua

Looking to a way in lua to get last time an file was modified, on windows

I have seen  this post [How can I get last modified timestamp in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296834/how-can-i-get-last-modified-timestamp-in-lua)
But is a solution for linux :/ can I use io.popen to get the string in windows also?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_file_time(filepath)
  local pipe = io.popen('dir /4/tw "'..filepath..'"')
  local output = pipe:read"*a"
  pipe:close()
  return output:match"\n(%d.-:%S*)"
end

local filepath = [[C:\path\to\your\file.ext]]  -- file must exist
print(get_file_time(filepath))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use luafilesystem the git https://github.com/keplerproject/luafilesystem
`lfs.attributes(<your file path>).modification` is what you searching for

it also work for both Windows and Linux
the manual https://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html

Comment: Thanks!!! This is Cooll! I wonder How Can I use this in a script of an not open source software ( REAPER ) , Is it possible?

Comment: just do
    `lastModification = lfs.attributes(<your file path>).modification`